# How to configure Apache2.2 to set HttpOnly and Secure parameter?

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, webserver, apache-config

Is there a way to directly configure apache (httpd.conf) to set HttpOnly and Secure parameter .. Or it has to be done progrmatically .. I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add mod_jk as well for https thing

update
check this article :

http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/

And let me know if this helps.

Comment: i have added "LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so" in httpd.conf